# Smooth points OpenGL ES 2.0 using shaders

Tags: ios4, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

I am drawing some points using glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, ...) and I would like to make them smooth round points instead of the squares. I know that there is no fixed function pipeline in OpenGL ES 2.0 so I am wondering if there is an easy way of doing this with the fragment shader?

Thanks in advance,

ExtremeCoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would render the point as a textured quad. That is straight forward, will do the job, works on even the oldest OpenGL versions and is probably faster than a shader.

Comment: The problem is that I need to color the different points and there are so many that I would need pretty much 256 ^ 3 different textures...

Comment: You can use a single GL_INTENSITY (graylevel) texture end set the color of the quads vertices with glColor3f().